# Print out secret[0] and modify secret[0] vulnerability attack

Tags: c, string, security, exploit, format-string

I have this lab to do and it's the C format string vulnerability. I have to do three things: crash the program, print out secret[0] or secret[1] value, and modify the secret[0] or secret[1]. I have successfully crashed the program. My question is how would I do the other two steps? I am not understanding how to do these steps and cannot find a good explanation that has helped me to understand it.

```
/* vul_prog.c */

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define SECRET1 0x44
#define SECRET2 0x55

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char user_input[100];
    int *secret;
    int int_input;
    int a, b, c, d; /* other variables, not used here.*/

    /* The secret value is stored on the heap */
    secret = (int *) malloc(2*sizeof(int));

    /* getting the secret */
    secret[0] = SECRET1; secret[1] = SECRET2;

    printf("The variable secret's address is 0x%8x (on stack)\n",(unsigned int)&secret);
    printf("The variable secret's value is 0x%8x (on heap)\n", (unsigned int)secret);
    printf("secret[0]'s address is 0x%8x (on heap)\n", (unsigned int)&secret[0]);
    printf("secret[1]'s address is 0x%8x (on heap)\n", (unsigned int)&secret[1]);

    printf("Please enter a decimal integer\n");
    scanf("%d", &int_input);  /* getting an input from user */
    printf("Please enter a string\n");
    scanf("%s", user_input); /* getting a string from user */

    /* Vulnerable place */
    printf(user_input);
    printf("\n");

    /* Verify whether your attack is successful */
    printf("The original secrets: 0x%x -- 0x%x\n", SECRET1, SECRET2);
    printf("The new secrets:      0x%x -- 0x%x\n", secret[0], secret[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
The variable secret's address is 0x5c349888 (on stack)
The variable secret's value is 0x49403250 (on heap)
secret[0]'s address is 0x49403250 (on heap)
secret[1]'s address is 0x49403254 (on heap)
Please enter a decimal integer
777
Please enter a string
%x,%x,%s
Segmentation fault: 11
```

But I am confused on how to find the secret and modify it.

Comment: Are you sure that you declare user_input[100] before the secret?